# How do i make connectors (lines connecting datalabels) of piechart in Highcharts look straight lines and not curved?

Tags: highcharts

I need my piechart datalabels connectors to be straight lines and not curved ones which is by default for pie of Highcharts

what i want
[image with straight connector lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHeQI.png)

currently it looks like this
[default pie with curved connector lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5jy7.png)

Here is my code

```
 Highcharts.chart('pieChart', {
    chart: {

        height: 274,
        borderColor: ''
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    colors: [
    ''
    ],
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            startAngle: 170,
            borderWidth:0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.percentage:f}%</b><br>{point.name} ',
                style: {
                    fontWeight:'normal',
                }
            },
            colors: [
            '#8cdfff', 
            '#a6e6ff', 
            '#67d5ff',
            '#3ac9ff', 
            '#00b5fa', 
            ],
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [{
            name: 'No Reason',
            y: 12
        }, {
            name: 'Sick',
            y: 13
        }, {
            name: 'Sent away',
            y: 15
        }, {
            name: 'Paid Leave',
            y: 20
        }, {
            name: 'Vacation',
            y: 40
        }],
        sliced: true,
        selected: true,
        dataLabels: {
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'Inter UI',
                fontSize: '12px',
                color: '#282d32',
            }
        },

        point: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: function (e) {
                    this.dataLabel.css({
                        fontWeight: "bold"
                        // color: "#4d5c61"
                    });
                },
                mouseOut: function (e) {
                    this.dataLabel.css({
                        fontWeight: "normal"
                        // color: "#808f9e"
                    });
                }
            },
        },
        type: 'pie'
    }],

    title: {
        text: '',
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ' ',
    }
});
```

If some kind soul can help me with it, I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

The default options are in `series.pie.dataLabels.connectorShape` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.connectorShape)). You can choose between `fixedOffset` (default), `straight` `crookedLine` or a function returning a SVG path.

You might want to choose `crookedLine`, as seen in [this JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-datalabels-connectorshape-string/). This is useful to combine with `crookDistance` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.crookDistance)). If you want to make it a specific shape you can also make it a function that returns a SVG path as seen in [this JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-datalabels-connectorshape-function/).

Example usage in options:

```
series: [{
    dataLabels: {
        connectorShape: 'crookedLine',
        crookDistance: '70%'
    },
    //...
}]
```